# Htaccess redirect after Magento site moved to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've moved my site with all its contents from the root to a subfolder, like

```
www.example.com
```

To

```
www.example.com/shop
```

Now, I want to redirect all old pages to the new url.

What I tried in the .htaccess of the root, but did'nt work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(shop)($|/) - [L]  // To prevent loops
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/shop$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now, all old pages redirect to example.com/shop

Edit:

After it was moved, I had to add following code to the htaccess of subdirectory to make it work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/shop/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^shop/ /shop%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This redirects to www.example.com/shop/index.php

Comment: Yes I checked but still unclear what's not working from my suggested code.

Comment: A link like www.example.com/product.html is redirected to www.example.com/shop/index.php instead of www.example.com/shop/product.html

Comment: And `/shop/product.html` is a valid file? Can you try this in a new browser?

Comment: Yes, url is valid. Other browsers same result. :(

Comment: Not URL is there a file called `/shop/product.html`?

Comment: It is a Magento productpage.

Comment: ok that explains so it is not a valid file. Let me edit the rule above.

Comment: Use a new browser to test.

Comment: Also remember Magento admin panel also has base URL you need to modify there also.

Comment: I have tried this exact setup in my local magento install and it worked fine.

Comment: Not for me. But +1 for efforts.

Comment: I had to change my base URLs (secured and non-secured) for this to work in my Magento